# plot dirac function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization

I'm trying to plot the Dirac delta function in Matlab using `plot`, but I don't see anything in the graph. How do I visualize it?

Comment: Discrete delta function or an approximation to a continuous (infinite height and unit integral) Direct delta function?  If so, which approximation?  Can you show what you're doing so far?  That will lend more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = -10 : 0.1 : 10;
y = double(x == 0);
plot(x, y);
```

or

```
stem(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using `dirac` and setting `Inf` to `1` or another amplitude.

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
y = dirac(x);
idx = y == Inf; % find Inf
y(idx) = 1;     % set Inf to some amplitude
stem(x,y)
```

Of course, the other answer is perfectly valid. This is just personal preference for being explicit.